# xml parsing and storing data

Tags: sql, xml, web-services, parsing, plsql

I have written a webservice from which i got some clob data as response and i need to convert into xml and then store the data into a table....

Can you help me how to do this

Comment: what do you mean by clob data? please explain.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you have the XMLTYPE column type. You can easily store a clob as xml.